# Simply Modbus Master not reading pins AI1 or AI2

Tags: serial-port, modbus

I am trying to read from a [Comet t3110 Temperature and Humidity sensor](http://www.comet-america.com/products/temperature-and-humidity-outdoor-indoor-probe-with-4-20ma-output/reg-t3110). I've hooked up the sensor to an ["mbsl6ad4di4do" analog-digital converter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/6AD4DI4DO-digital-input-and-output-analog-acquisition-module-RS485-MODBUS-RTU-communication/32470130085.html) and ive connected the converter to a serial to usb adapter which is connected to the computer. the wiring setup looks something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmbuP.jpg)

The problem I'm having is that the holding registers which correspond to pins AI1 and AI2 (at least according to what little documentation i have) are returning no data. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGbMu.png) is a screenshot of what the modbus master looks like.

as you can see most of the registers are empty aside from the ones corresponding to the device address, baudrate, check bit, and product version (The register for the function code selection is actually also displaying data; 0 is just the assigned bit for the default function as far as i know). I don't know much about serial communication to begin with, but ive been reading and re-reading the documentation on the retailers page for the converter and on the simply modbus website. i have tried cycling through the different data types in the response table but that hasn't gotten me anywhere. not sure what else to try. any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you probed the two analog outputs to see what they are doing? Also why are there two analog lines is it two separate measurements or is it like a differential reading?

Comment: The 2 485 pins seem to be communicating fine. There are two readings coming from the sensor. One for temperature and one for humidity.

Comment: gotcha, I think it’s wired wrong. I’m no expert but see my explanation below and make sure that checks out.

Comment: From page 6 of instruction manual output I1 is relative humidity, and I2 is temperature. From your diagram there’s no way humidity can be measured because it’s not connected to the A to D and there will be no current to measure for I2 because there is no voltage potential to drive it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I read about 4-20mA current analog sensors you need the +I2 and -I2 to form a loop with the supply voltage (same with +I1 and -I1) see page 17 of the T3110 Instruction Manual. It doesn’t look like your having issues with serial communication as the returned address values match the factory defaults.

You should double check this but I think you want positive voltage (V+) to go into +I2 and connect -I2 to AI1. Probably want to connect +I1 to V+ and -I1 to AI2.

That’s just my guess so think it over. I haven’t really worked with these much but I hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect! that's giving me a reading now! Now all i have to do is convert that output into the proper units! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure thing, glad it worked out! Can you upvote the answer?

Comment: I did, but my rep is low so it says it's counted but not displayed :/

Comment: Oh gotcha, appreciate it anyway. Good luck